# Exclusive access of particular java class in intellij idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am developing android application in Intellij idea with private repository BitBucket. my problem is i want to add functionality like Exclusive access of particular file means if i doing some work in particular file then my friend should not allow to edit that file unless i commit it and leave that file. (ex. visual source safe)

Comment: what vsc type do you choose on BitBucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, git and mercurial don't provide lock system which will not allow you to lock some files on bitbucket if you choose such VCS.

In most cases, when you work with a distributed VCS, you should not need lock mecanism as merging branches is really easy.

Cheers

Comment: +1 thanks for support..:):)and yes you right i have just contacted that team and got the same response